# How to redirect to page wanted after successful login?

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I had successful send an alert email for the event that was expired. From the email there is a link to enable user to link back that particular event details. If the user haven't login it will redirect to login page. Once login successful, it will return to home page. How if I want to redirect to the specific event page after login?

```
     $contractid = $_REQUEST['Contract_ID'];
$contract_update_url = "contract_updates.php?id=".$contractid;
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "news_mgm.php";

if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])){

header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );}


if(!empty ($contactid))
       {       
            header("Location: " . $contract_update_url );

       }
       else{

      // header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
      header("Location: javascript://history.go(-1)");
       }
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to pass something about event (for example, event ID) to the link on the email.

Then you can keep this event ID while processing user login and if it's OKAY - do redirect to event page by event ID.